# Storing GET method returned data into variable

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, get

The below code fetches text from an URL (Which is readable in debug console), But I am having trouble accessing that data as a variable that I can then use elsewhere.

The code currently produces "data is not iterable" errors and I have tried JSON.parse(ing) the data without much success.

If I for example wanted to print the fetched data onto the body of the page, How would I go about doing that?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#ajaxButton").click(function() {
    $.get("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming?type=single", function(data, status) {
      console.log(data);

      var addStr = "";
      for (var x of data) {
        addStr += "<p>" + x.Any + "</p>";
      }

      $("#here").html(addStr);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here"></div>
<p id="joke">Want to hear a joke?</p>
<br>
<button id="ajaxButton">yes</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is because the deserialised response isn't an array, it's an object. This is why you can't iterate it in your `for` loop.

To do what you require simply output the content of the `joke` property in the response to the UI:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  const $here = $('#here');

  $("#ajaxButton").on('click', function() {
    $.get("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming?type=single", response => {
      $here.html(`<p>${response.joke}</p>`);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="joke">Want to hear a joke?</p>
<div id="here"></div>
<button id="ajaxButton">yes</button>
```